# VBA: forwarding types through sub-routine call argument

Tags: vba, types

My first entrance here.

Coding VBA, fairly unfamiliar.

=================================================================

Objective: Input coordinates into an object/class.

... means "and so on"

Solution now: using array, such as

=================================================================

class1:

```
sub start()
    Dim c2 as new Class2
    Dim points() as Double
    Redim points(7)
    point(0) = ...
    ...
    point(7) = ...
    cs.draw points
end sub
```

class2:

```
public Sub draw(points() as double)
    ...
end sub
```

=================================================================

Problem is: hard keep track witch array-slot represents a particular value of interest.

What I want to do, is something like:

class 1:

```
Type Properties
    length As Double
    keygripp As Double
    diameter As Double
    tapdiameter As Double
    steerlength As Double
    distance As Double

    plateau As Double
End Type


sub start()
    Dim c2 as new Class2
    Dim points as Properties
    point.length = ...
    ...
    point.plateau = ...
    cs.draw points
end sub
```

class2:

```
public Sub draw(p as Properties) '<---- Class 2 also need access to properties?
    ...
    doCoolStuff(p.length)
    doOtherCoolStuff(p.keygripp, p.diameter)
    ...
end sub
```

do I declare the Type Properties global somehow so that class1 and class2 both will know what it is about?

Regards // Martin

Comment: VB.NET, VBA and VBScript are all different. Please [edit] and remove the irrelevant tags. Please also see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Not sure what you wish me to edit, only "VBA" and "Types" as tags.

Comment: It looks to have already been [done](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43628561/revisions) AutoMartin by Lankymart.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you could create e.g. `Point` class and use it in a collection and then pass instance of this collection to the `Draw` method. HTH

*Note: The name `Point` corresponds with the name `Properties` in your question.*

> Point Class Module

```
Option Explicit

Private m_length As Double

Public Property Get Length() As Double
    Length = m_length
End Property

Public Property Let Length(ByVal vNewValue As Double)
    m_length = vNewValue
End Property

' Tha same as by lenght for the next properties
'    keygripp As Double
'    diameter As Double
'    tapdiameter As Double
'    steerlength As Double
'    distance As Double
'    plateau As Double
```

> Processor Class Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Draw(pts As VBA.Collection)
    Dim p As Point
    For Each p In pts
        ' ...
        ' doCoolStuff p.Length
        ' doOtherCoolStuff p.keygripp, p.diameter
        ' ...
    Next p
End Sub
```

> Standard Module

```
Sub Start()
    Dim pt As Point
    Set pt = New Point
    pt.Length = 123
    ' pt.plateau = ...

    Dim points As VBA.Collection
    Set points = New VBA.Collection
    points.Add pt

    Dim proc As Processor
    Set proc = New Processor
    proc.Draw points
End Sub
```

---

If you wish to stay by the user defined type, then in standard module declare the type and then use it with array (UDT can't be used with `VBA.Collection`).

> Standard Module

```
Type PointType
    length As Double
    keygripp As Double
    diameter As Double
    tapdiameter As Double
    steerlength As Double
    distance As Double
    plateau As Double
End Type

Sub start()
    Dim pt As PointType
    pt.length = 555

    Dim pt2 As PointType
    pt2.length = 666

    Dim pts(1 To 2) As PointType
    pts(1) = pt
    pts(2) = pt2

    Dim proc As Processor
    Set proc = New Processor
    proc.Draw pts
End Sub
```

> Class Processor

```
Public Sub Draw(pts() As PointType)
' use for-next isnatead of for-each-next here
```